# How to apply png masking in pixijs?

Tags: javascript, css, pixi.js

I am trying to apply a png sprite as mask for another layer.
I got the demo from pixi.js official website and made this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/raphadko/ukc1rwrc/

This is the core code for the masking that I'm using:

```
var brush =  PIXI.Sprite.fromImage('http://i.imgur.com/LtSbbSP.png');
brush.anchor.set(0.5);
app.stage.addChild(brush);
brush.x = app.renderer.width / 2;
brush.y = app.renderer.height / 2;

var thing = new PIXI.Graphics();
app.stage.addChild(thing);
thing.x = app.renderer.width / 2;
thing.y = app.renderer.height / 2;
thing.lineStyle(0);

container.mask = thing;
```

You can see that the masking works well when it is applied the "things" object (which is not a sprite but a Graphics() element. Now if you change lines 31 and 37 to apply the sprite named brush instead, masking does not work.
(Clicking turns mask on and off)

How to make masking work for png sprites?

Answer (score 5):

When using Sprite as a mask, bright areas are visible while dark areas are hidden. Using a white colored image will make the png mask work correctly.

```
var brush =  PIXI.Sprite.fromImage('https://0201.nccdn.net/1_2/000/000/11a/e17/house-xxl.png');
```

Following is the updated fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/ukc1rwrc/4/

Answer (score 3):

I found this question searching for a solution to the same problem, I realise it's an old problem but it might help future Pixi, erm, pixies.

The issue is that altho it's known as alpha masking, it works on both alpha and colour - my knowledge of GLSL is limited but it looks like the shader that performs the mask takes the red channel, I'm guessing because working out the true luminosity of each RGB pixel would be expensive.

So a black area (red = 0) on a PNG will mask the target Display Object, just as a transparent area (alpha = 0) would. This allows you to use JPGs as well.

"Official" confirmation in [this](https://github.com/pixijs/pixi.js/issues/1639) thread.
Shader definition [here](https://github.com/pixijs/pixi.js/blob/dev/src/core/renderers/webgl/filters/spriteMask/spriteMaskFilter.frag).